# Ruby: How to access the constant defined in a anonymous class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can access the constant `AGE` as A::AGE. How do I access the constant `NAME`?(as `A::NAME` throws an error.)

```
class A
  AGE=24
  class << self
    NAME="foo"
  end
end
```

**Note:** I am trying to access the constants outside the class A.

**Note 2:** I am on Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: where do you want to access it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ruby 1.9.x, Ruby provides the method `singleton_class`. So the call

```
irb(main):009:0> A.singleton_class::NAME
=> "foo"
```

does  what you want to do.

---

In Ruby 1.8.x, you may implement the method `singleton_class` on your own:

```
class Object
  def singleton_class
    class << self; self; end
  end
end
```

Then you are able to call:

```
A.singleton_class::NAME
=> "foo"
```

This is possible due to the fact that Ruby classes are all the time open for extensions and changes.

Comment: You should have added "Ruby 1.9".

Comment: I haved added that the nice solution only works for Ruby 1.9.x, and added a workaround to Ruby 1.8.x (which may or may not help you).

Comment: The Rails framework provides support for `singleton_class` in Ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 1):

Define the constant with:

```
self::NAME = "foo"
```

This will explicitly bind it to `self`.

Comment: I am trying to access a constant defined in a third party gem. So I have not control over it.

Comment: This answer was helpful to me as I was defining anonymous classes to test mixins that rely on class constants